# Jadira 6.0 Integration with Hibernate 4.3

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been trying to use Jadira 6.0 with Hibernate 4.3.11.FINAL and getting the following exception

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method org/jadira/usertype/dateandtime/threeten/PersistentZonedDateTime.nullSafeGet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;[Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; is abstract
at org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentZonedDateTime.nullSafeGet(PersistentZonedDateTime.java)
at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:127)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:106)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1696)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1628)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1515)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:726)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1718)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
```

I am trying to map a ZonedDateTime field

```
    @Column(name = "dn_date", nullable = false)
  @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentZonedDateTime")
    private ZonedDateTime date;
```

The PersistentZonedDateTime does not exist in versions prior to 6 from what I can tell.  I cannot find anything that states which version(s) of hibernate is supported for each version of Jadira.

I cannot upgrade to hibernate 5 right now.  Can someone familiar with Jadira shed some light on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It really seems to be something with hibernate integration implemented in jadira version 6.X.

My stack was:

- jadira 6.0.1.GA
- hibernate 5.0.12.Final

And had the same error (note that I was using hibernate 5.0.X).

Now my stack looks like this and everything works fine:

- jadira **6.0.1.GA**
- hibernate **5.2.16.Final**